Angular Material doesn't load certain icons
Using angular (17.2.1), @angular/material (17.3.7) and I can't seem to load certain icons coming from Google Fonts Icons. An example of an icon that isn't loading is e911_emergency.
This is how I'm using the icons:
<button mat-fab extended [mat-dialog-close]="'emergency'">
      <mat-icon>e911_emergency</mat-icon>
      Emergency
</button>

I've installed @angular/material using ng add @angular/material.
This is my index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

StackBlitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5sfz4z?file=src%2Fmain.ts (here I am using Angular v18 and STILL doesn't work!)


Import the Material Symbols Outlined stylesheet.

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined"
/>


Specify the fontSet attribute to both  elements.

<mat-icon fontSet="material-symbols-outlined">e911_emergency</mat-icon>

Demo @ StackBlitz
Key points:

By default, Material icons font is used.
If you face that the icon is not rendering, it is due to the specified icon does not belong to the Material icons font stylesheet.
Browse the specified icons in the Google Fonts website and check the required stylesheet.
Import the required stylesheet to the root application (index.html).
Add the fontSet attribute with the class name as in Point 3.

For importing icons that are not Google Fonts icons (for example Font Awesome), the same steps should be taken by importing the stylesheet and adding the fontSet attribute to the <mat-icon> element.
Reference: Mat Icon

Would you mind adapting this answer to work with some icons that may not be in the Material Symbols Outlined stylesheet (basically, generalizing)? Thanks to your answer, I saw from the Google Fonts website that on the right the stylesheet is specified. If you could make this edit I'll gladly accept this as the answer.

Hi, so for the other icons from other stylesheets will also work as same approach. Import the stylesheet and specify the fontSet in the mat-icon. For your reference: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIcon

Yes, however right now the answer isn't complete, if you could write this in the answer so everybody having this issue can directly read it without having to read the comments would be awesome :)

Updated my answer, hope it explains clearly.

you can hide icons until the fonts are loaded by adding display=block in the link tag
here is the comple


<link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined&display=block"
      rel="stylesheet" />



te link
